# How to Data Bind the ActualHeight of a Parent Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wrappanel

I have a Window that has a UserControl. What i want to accomplish is Bind the ActualHeight of the StackPanel (stackpanel doesn't have a fixed size) that contains the UserControl in order to achive the correct behavior of the WrapPanel inside the UserControl.

I've tried `Height="{Binding ElementName=MyStackPanel, Path=ActualHeight}"` and `Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=ActualHeight}"` but it didn't worked.

The way i place the UserControl inside the Window's StackPanel is as follows:

```
     <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
         <!-- Wrap Panel / UserControl-->
         <local:WrapControl />
     </StackPanel>
```

If it helps the Main Window is a devexpress `DXRibbonWindow`.

Comment: Is `MyStackPanel` identical to `stkTop`? The Height of which control do you want to bind? It's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please add some details.

Comment: yes. i am sorry...i will correct it.

Comment: Still not clear which Height you want to bind, i.e. at which control you tried to set `Height="{Binding ...}`.

Comment: I've tried to bind with `MyStackPanel`'s height. The `WrapControl` has a `WrapPanel` with some `Expanders` inside it. So i just want to move the expanders that doesn't fit when they expand, to the right. I've tried to set `Height=...` to the `WrapPanel` inside my `WrapControl` `UserControl`.

Comment: The `WrapPanel`'s `Height`.

Comment: As long as the StackPanel does not vertically stretch to the size of its parent (the Window?), its ActualHeight will be determined by the sum of the ActualHeights of its Children. So it doesn't make sense to set the Height of the WrapPanel to the ActualHeight of the StackPanel. Try to set the VerticalAlignment properties of the panels instead. You may also try to use a Grid instead of the StackPanel, because it stretches its Children by default.

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you @Clemens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems that `StackPanel` has no concept of "stretching" to occupy all the space available.

Replacing the `StackPanel` with a `Grid` works perfect.

Comment: You don't need that binding. The Grid stretches its child elements by default (unless you change their HorizontalAlignment or VerticalAlignment).